# how do I launch an nginx docker container with a site that is copied to the container?

Tags: docker, nginx, dockerfile

I wrote such a docker file, run the container and open localhost, opens nginx, although the site should open from the /var/www/html folder . How to solve the problem?

```
FROM nginx

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install zip
WORKDIR  /02_Continuous_Delivery/html
COPY . /var/www/html
RUN rm -f /var/www/html/site.zip; zip -r /var/www/html/site.zip /02_Continuous_Delivery/html
EXPOSE 80
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have a solution

```
FROM nginx

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install zip

COPY 02_Continuous_Delivery/html /usr/share/nginx/html
RUN zip -r /usr/share/nginx/html/site.zip /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
#CMD ["nginx","-g","daemon off;"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that by default nginx image provides config (*/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf*) like this:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    listen  [::]:80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
}
```

So, you should either copy your site to */usr/share/nginx/html* directory or provide your custom config and set there location root as */var/www/html* directory.

For second solution you can create file *default.conf* with content like:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    listen  [::]:80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
        root   /var/www/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
}
```

and copy it to */etc/nginx/conf.d/* directory in your Dockerfile

```
COPY default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/
```

Comment: Thx for solution